# C++11 forwarding Template template parameter does not work

Tags: c++11, templates, perfect-forwarding

I used template template parameter as follows:

```
    /* [1]: Definition containing a template template parameter */
          template <typename T, template<class> class Kernel>
          void ForEach(Kernel<T> kernel, T * pSrc, int elementCount) {
               //....
          }

    /* [2]: Definition of a helper struct */
          template <typename T> struct KernelStd {  
               //...
          };

    /* [3]: Use the previous definitions */
          float arr1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

          //The following two calls to ForEach do successfully compile
          ForEach(KernelStd<float>(), arr1, 5); //USE1
          ForEach<float>(KernelStd<float>(), arr1, 5); //USE2

    /* [4]: Definition of a helper function */      
          template <typename F, typename ...Args>
          void forwarder(F func1, Args && ...args) {
                //...
                func1(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
          }
          //But the following callS do not compile.
          forwarder(ForEach, KernelStd<float>(), arr1, 5); //USE3
          forwarder(ForEach<float>, KernelStd<float>(), arr1, 5); //USE4
```

I am using VS2013 update 5 and I get the following error:

```
         error C2783: 'void ForEach(Kernel<T>,T *,int)' : could not deduce 
         template argument for 'Kernel'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's `ForEach`? Is it related in some way to `transform`? What's `KernelStd`? Is it related in some way to `Kernel1`? It would be best if you show [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes in my code fragment. I have fixed those.

Answer (score 1):

`forwarder` is a function, so its first argument must be an entity (object or function) of type `F`.

`ForEach` is neither a function nor an object, it's a *template.* You therefore cannot pass `ForEach` to `forwarder`.

`ForEach<float>` does not pass enough template arguments to fully identify a function instantiated from the `ForEach` template. You can get away with it when calling the function template because of template argument deduction. But in the context of `forwarder`, the type `F` is supposed to be deduced from the first argument, so you have a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem.

If you want to use `forwarder`, you must supply it with an actual function, not with a template. So you'd have to do this:

```
forwarder(ForEach<float, KernelStd>, KernelStd<float>(), arr1, 5);
```

`ForEach<float, KernelStd>` contains all template arguments and it therefore designates a *function* (instantiated from a template).